# MediaElement: how to simultaneously play same sound?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, audio, mediaelement

There is MediaElement in XAML:

```
<MediaElement Source="sound.mp3" AutoPlay="False" x:Name="Sound"></MediaElement>
<Button x:Name="Control" Content="Button" Click="Control_Click_1"/>
```

And code:

```
Private Sub Control_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Sound.Stop() // rewind to start
    Sound.Play()
End Sub
```

I want to combine same sound few times by clicking button. Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried having multiple `MediaElement` objects all pointing at the same source and choosing them in sequence? A single MediaElement cannot play the same source more than one (it is not a mixer).